# Idiomatic Clojure function alias

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, idioms

What would be the most idiomatic way to alias a function in Clojure ?
And is there any difference in terms of execution between those two approaches ?

Example taken from [Om](https://github.com/omcljs/om/blob/master/src/main/om/next.cljs#L883) (Clojurescript, but the syntax in Clojure would be the same):

```
(defn query->ast
  "Given a query expression convert it into an AST."
  [query-expr]
  (parser/query->ast query-expr))

(def query->ast
  "Given a query expression convert it into an AST."
  parser/query->ast)
```

Comment: The second approach is the idiomatic answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer `def` to `defn`.

The `defn` version

- has an interposed function call, which may or may not be elided;
- is restricted to arity 1, whereas the `def` version has all the arities of
  the original.

Comment: You could build the multi-arity into the new `defn`, but it's not worth the trouble; your first reason is enough of a reason.